# how to recognize interupt handler on register level of efr32fg14

Tags: embedded

in the code bellow we have interrupt functions which play with the IF register.
And there are functions called USART0_RX_IRQHandler
functions which we dont call in the main() and in the function itself there is USART_IntDisable which does usart->IEN &= ~flags.
But i cant see no where in the code bellow to activate USART0_RX_IRQHandler when ever transmition comes.
Where is this mechanism?

Thanks.

```
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"

#include "bsp.h"

// Size of the buffer for received data
#define BUFLEN  80

// Receive data buffer
uint8_t buffer[BUFLEN];

// Current position ins buffer
uint32_t inpos = 0;
uint32_t outpos = 0;

// True while receiving data (waiting for CR or BUFLEN characters)
bool receive = true;

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief
 *    GPIO initialization
 *****************************************************************************/
void initGpio(void)
{
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);

  // Configure VCOM transmit pin to board controller as an output
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_BCC_TXPORT, BSP_BCC_TXPIN, gpioModePushPull, 1);

  // Configure VCOM reeive pin from board controller as an input
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_BCC_RXPORT, BSP_BCC_RXPIN, gpioModeInput, 0);

  // Enable VCOM connection to board controller
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_BCC_ENABLE_PORT, BSP_BCC_ENABLE_PIN, gpioModePushPull, 1);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief
 *    USART0 initialization (VCOM on xG1/xG12/xG13 boards)
 *****************************************************************************/
void initUsart0(void)
{
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART0, true);

  // Default asynchronous initializer (115.2 Kbps, 8N1, no flow control)
  USART_InitAsync_TypeDef init = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT;

  // Configure and enable USART0
  USART_InitAsync(USART0, &init);

  // Enable NVIC USART sources
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_TX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART0_TX_IRQn);

  // Enable RX and TX for USART0 VCOM connection
  USART0->ROUTELOC0 = BSP_BCC_RX_LOCATION | BSP_BCC_TX_LOCATION;
  USART0->ROUTEPEN |= USART_ROUTEPEN_RXPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_TXPEN;
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief
 *    The USART0 receive interrupt saves incoming characters.
 *****************************************************************************/
void USART0_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  // Get the character just received
  buffer[inpos] = USART0->RXDATA;

  // Exit loop on new line or buffer full
  if ((buffer[inpos] != '\r') && (inpos < BUFLEN))
    inpos++;
  else
    receive = false;   // Stop receiving on CR

  // Clear the requesting interrupt before exiting the handler
  USART_IntClear(USART0, USART_IF_RXDATAV);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief
 *    The USART0 transmit interrupt outputs characters.
 *****************************************************************************/
void USART0_TX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  // Send a previously received character
  if (outpos < inpos)
    USART0->TXDATA = buffer[outpos++];
  else
  /*
   * Need to disable the transmit buffer level interrupt in this IRQ
   * handler when done or it will immediately trigger again upon exit
   * even though there is no data left to send.
   */
  {
    receive = true;   // Go back into receive when all is sent
    USART_IntDisable(USART0, USART_IEN_TXBL);
  }
  // Clear the requesting interrupt before exiting the handler
  USART_IntClear(USART0, USART_IF_TXBL);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief
 *    Main function
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  uint32_t i;

  // Chip errata
  CHIP_Init();

  // Initialize GPIO and USART0
  initGpio();
  initUsart0();

  while (1)
  {
    // Zero out buffer
    for (i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++)
      buffer[i] = 0;

    // Enable receive data valid interrupt
    USART_IntEnable(USART0, USART_IEN_RXDATAV);

    // Wait in EM1 while receiving to reduce current draw
    while (receive)
      EMU_EnterEM1();

    // Disable receive data valid interrupt
    USART_IntDisable(USART0, USART_IEN_RXDATAV);

    // Enable transmit buffer level interrupt
    USART_IntEnable(USART0, USART_IEN_TXBL);

    // Wait in EM1 while transmitting to reduce current draw
    while (!receive)
      EMU_EnterEM1();

    // Reset buffer indices
    inpos = outpos = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the real problem behind the question is something more like "I don't understand how interrupts work", and not only does that seem to broad of a problem to solve here, there is plenty of reference material to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the USART_IntEnable() line with the comment "Enable receive data valid interrupt".

Comment: Its just enabling the flag ,where in the register level we say to activate function USART0_RX_IRQHandler in this case?

Comment: Perhaps there is some more general issue with understanding how interrupts work? Yes, that line enables the interrupt, i.e. allows it to execute if necessary. It is only executed if it is enabled, and then UART receives a character and then the UART triggers the CPU core with an interrupt so the CPU goes to run the code for that specific interrupt.

Comment: Its something with  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn) function but i can its roots to the registers of efr32fg14

Comment: the NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn) is the closest thing but it not calling the hander function

Comment: I don't understand why you think the interrupt handler is called via other code. It is not. Nobody explicitly calls the interrupt handler. When receive interrupts are enabled and data is received, and the interrupt is signaled to CPU, the CPU stops executing what it was doing and jumps to execute the interrupt code and then returns to execute what it was doing.

Comment: Hello, there are functions names like NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ , NVIC_EnableIRQ , USART0_RX_IRQHandler. i cant see the dynamics of those names.how they work together?
Is there some total manual for them? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely there is a manual from the manufacturer. Sounds like standard Cortex-M ARM architecture. NVIC is the interrupt controller. But are you specifically lost how interrupts work on your specific MCU, or on Cortex-M, or the concept of how interrupts work in general?